# Should I extend my type with extra fields or create a new type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I have TODO templates which are used to create todos in todo lists.
Should I create one type for both templates and created todos like this:

```
type TODO {
    id: ID
    text: String
    type: String
    templateId: ID
    completed: Boolean
}
type TODOList {
    id: ID
    todos: [TODO]
    owner: String
}
```

Or should I make separate types for templates and created todos?

```
type TODO {
    id: ID
    text: String
    type: String
    templateId: ID
    completed: Boolean
}
type TODOTemplate {
    id: ID
    templateType: String
    templateText: String
}
type TODOList {
    id: ID
    todos: [TODO]
    owner: String
}
```

Or maybe there is more convenient method and I am doing everything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the second one looks better since you've introduced extra fields and probably want access to them. in that case you'll want to revise your TODO type:

```
type TODO {
    id: ID
    text: String
    type: String
    template: TODOTemplate
    completed: Boolean
}
```